# Onsen sliding menu with tabbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

Below is what I've tried. Basically, if you add the tabbar the sliding menu does not work anymore. Clicking on nav button top left does nothing.

**Plnkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/VZoEO78HiUYnNFVqh1sx?p=preview

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link data-require="onsen_ui@*" data-semver="1.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsenui.css" />
  <link data-require="onsen_ui@*" data-semver="1.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" />
  <script data-require="onsen_ui@*" data-semver="1.0.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="onsen_ui@*" data-semver="1.0.3" src="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/js/onsenui.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <ons-sliding-menu main-page="services.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="left" max-slide-distance="250px" var="menu"></ons-sliding-menu>

  <ons-tabbar>
          <ons-tab page="services.html" label="services" icon="square" active="true"></ons-tab>
          <ons-tab page="products.html" label="products" icon="square"></ons-tab>
        </ons-tabbar>

  <script>
    angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
    angular.module('app')
      .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
      });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**menu.html:**

```
<ons-list>
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('services.html', {closeMenu: true})">
  services.html
</ons-list-item>
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('products.html', {closeMenu: true})">
  products.html
</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

**services.html:**

```
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
  <div class="left">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
      <ons-icon icon="fa-bars" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
    </ons-toolbar-button>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Services</div>
</ons-toolbar>

    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item>Service 1</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>Service 2</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>Service 3</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
```

**products.html**

```
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
  <div class="left">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
      <ons-icon icon="fa-bars" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
    </ons-toolbar-button>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Products</div>
</ons-toolbar>

    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item>Product 1</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>Product 2</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item>Product 3</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write two components in the same level like your `ons-sliding-menu` and `ons-tabbar`. You need to put one inside another like this:

```
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="tabbar.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="left" max-slide-distance="250px" var="menu"></ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="tabbar.html">
  <ons-tabbar>
     <ons-tab page="services.html" label="services" icon="square" active="true"></ons-tab>
     <ons-tab page="products.html" label="products" icon="square"></ons-tab>
  </ons-tabbar>
</ons-template>
```

Hope it helps!